# remove slash from URLs by sed

Tags: ubuntu, awk, sed

If I do have URLs like that

```
https:/www.sony.com/SonyInfo/News/Press/202004/20-0416E////
http:/www.sony.com.au/section/careers///
http:/www.sony.com.au/section/careers////
http:/www.sony.com.my/electronics/careers////
http:/www.sony.com.ph/electronics/careers////
http:/www.sony.com.sg/section/careers///
```

How can I remove the last slashes from the urls by using sed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it following way, let `file.txt` content be

```
https:/www.sony.com/SonyInfo/News/Press/202004/20-0416E////
http:/www.sony.com.au/section/careers///
http:/www.sony.com.au/section/careers////
http:/www.sony.com.my/electronics/careers////
http:/www.sony.com.ph/electronics/careers////
http:/www.sony.com.sg/section/careers///
```

then

```
sed 's|/*$||' file.txt
```

gives output

```
https:/www.sony.com/SonyInfo/News/Press/202004/20-0416E
http:/www.sony.com.au/section/careers
http:/www.sony.com.au/section/careers
http:/www.sony.com.my/electronics/careers
http:/www.sony.com.ph/electronics/careers
http:/www.sony.com.sg/section/careers
```

Explanation: I use `|` as sed delimiter rather than `/` so I do not escape `/`, I replace zero-or-more (`*`) slash (`/`) immediately before end of line (`$`) using empty string, i.e. delete it

*(tested in GNU sed 4.7)*